# R Markdown: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've developed a shiny app that allows user to download a HTML report via R Markdown. I'm trying to include custom css and images into my rmarkdown file. However, I keep getting this error message:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch (either css or image file)
openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

When I knit the .rmd file on R Studio, it is able to reference the image file or css that I want. However, when I run the Shiny app and download the html file, I get the above error message. I've even tried to put the images and css files in the same working directory as the .rmd file, but to no avail...

```
output:
  html_document:
   css: pandoc.css

(same error message as above)
```

Been trying to find a solution for this but can't seem to...can anyone help here?

Comment: I got same error. Hope someone can fix it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I was not using the full file path. I was using ~/path/to/file. I changed it to the full path (i.e. removed the ~/) and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Haloom for the answer. Just to add on, for the benefit of everyone, Pandoc seems to be able to reference file path with empty spaces, so you can just reference it via "/Home/My Folder", no need for any escape backslash or quotes.

Comment: I thought that ~/ is the full path. Leaving the ~ is surely not correct, but replacing ~ with e.g. /home/user.The direction at least is right.

Comment: And in Wsl, you have to create a network drive as UNC Paths are not working.

Answer (score 22):

I just had this issue as well, but for me the reason was that the RStudio project was on a shared drive, and I had opened it through the network location. The problem was resolved when I closed out of the project, and opened it back up through a mapped network drive. (If when you run `getwd()` your location starts with `\\`, this is probably what is happening to you.)

Comment: how does one open a file "through a mapped network drive"? Thanks!

Comment: First, you'll need to know the network location you're trying to access. Next, in the Windows file manager, you will need to right click on "This PC" on the right hand pane, and select "Map a network drive". Go through the dialogue to define the network location from earlier as a lettered drive. Now you have two ways to get to the file you're opening. Using the drive-letter path should work.

Comment: Thanks @AColeman!  Any idea WHY this issue might have emerged?  I have no recollection of changing these types of directory settings.

Comment: I think it's an issue with Pandoc, which rmarkdown inherits because it uses Pandoc. But truth be told I haven't looked into it that much since figuring out the work-around.

Comment: When I had this issue I was using a machine that did not have WSL installed. Not saying it can't also cause the same issue, but I do know in my case that wasn't the cause.

Comment: I went through a lot of pain because I only skimmed this answer, but for those similarly challenged as me... Monkey see '\\' or '\\\\' -  Monkey replace with 'X:\' or whichever the network drive is of choice...

Comment: I don't have permissions to map, so I tried moving the project directory as well as the installation of R and RStudio to an already mapped drive (changing the libPaths accordingly). It worked.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into the issue on my Windows work-computer where I simply set the `.libPaths()` in the `Rprofile.site` file. This in line with previous answers but a little more detailed.

## Step 1

Check your current paths:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "\\\\my_work_server.se/some_subdir$/username/Dokument/R/win-library/3.6"
[2] "C:/R/R-3.6.3/library"
```

## Step 2

Look for the `\\\`, in this case it is the path `"\\\\my_work_server.se/some_subdir$/username/Dokument/R/win-library/3.6"`. This path is most likely some already mounted home directory, in my case it is `H:` = `"\\\\my_work_server.se/some_subdir$/username/`. If you don't have a mounted directory you may want to fix this first or change the library path to another.

## Step 3

So if you've installed R under `C:/R/R-3.6.3/` you edit the file `C:/R/R-3.6.3/etc/Rprofile.site` and add:

```
.First <- function(){
  .libPaths(c("H:/Dokument/R/win-library/3.6", "C:/R/R-3.6.3/library"))
}
```

Remember to change `H:` to where you have your mounted network directory.

## Step 4

That's it, restart R and you should be able to knit your document.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I had with RStudio & the pandoc error (openBinaryFile error) was due to the file path in which the project was created and loaded.

[Project File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRKGF.png)

When I created the project, I created it using the Universal path, which is the 2nd option in the image above.  However, when I changed this to the mapped drive letter, the option above it, my pandoc error was gone.

I'm running RStudio 1.2.1335 and R version 3.4.4

Answer (score 1):

I have been having a similar issue, with RStudio, rmarkdown and pandoc on a windows machine with network filestore. I followed various advice, mapped the drive to a letter and it still didn't help.

Eventually, I discovered that one of the paths in my libPaths contained the network location/Universal path. I updated that libpath to the mapped letter drive and everything seems to be going well!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message, but in my case the problem was that I used a `#` symbol in one of the chunk titles:

````
```{r show distribution of # of commits per month}
````

Which is no problem if you just run the notebook in Rstudio, but apparently confuses knitr/pandoc: when knitting, I got an error message like

```
pandoc: <path>/figure-html/show distribution of : openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`)
```

Removing the `#` from the chunk title solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I appreciate that you take the effort to improve (formatting) issues; in this case, chuck headers in R markdown do actually start with ```{r ... , so I would prefer to keep the snippet as it was...

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same message when running:

```
pandoc -s foo.html foo.md
```

Where I totally missed the `-o` flag as it should have been

```
pandoc -s -o foo.html foo.md
```

With the latter, everything is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I had the same issue. I first had tried [Changing the Default Directory](https://www.accelebrate.com/library/how-to-articles/r-rstudio-library) but every time I went to knit the RMarkdown file, I would get the same set of errors indicating that the process was still trying to access files on my Network's H drive rather that my local C drive, specifically it was looking in the rmarkdown library file on the network drive. I thought I was following the advice above, but after that did not work I tried deleting the rmarkdown folder in the network drive

eg: `\\fwnew12\Home\My Documents\R\win-library\3.6\rmarkdown`.

This seemed to force R to only use my local C drive (`C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library`) and finally successfully knit a PDF. Maybe this is not a recommended approach, but I just need something that works.