# pandoc: "No such file or directory" when converting file with Unicode characters in filename

Tags: windows, unicode, utf-8, filenames, pandoc

Using the [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) tool on Windows 11, I am trying to convert to HTML a Markdown file with Unicode characters in its name with the following command:

```
pandoc -f markdown_phpextra -o 'Ahoj sv─¢te.html' 'Ahoj sv─¢te.md'
```

But pandoc complains with the following error:

```
[WARNING] Could not deduce format from file extension
  Defaulting to html
pandoc.exe: svÄ>te.html': openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Any ideas how to make pandoc understand the filenames containing Unicode characters correctly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pandoc, but does this help at all?.... [R Markdown: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48161177/2985643). That error relates to a _css_ file rather than an _html_ file, but based on some of the answers the file path may be more relevant than the file type anyway.

Comment: Also, does everything work if your input and output file names do not contain spaces, and are not wrapped with single quotes? For example, something like: `pandoc -f markdown_phpextra -o Ahojsv─¢te.html Ahojsv─¢te.md`

Comment: Looks like a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python for its common intelligibility): `'světe'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp437')` ->`'sv─¢te'` and `'světe'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` -> `'svÄ›te'`.

Comment: Try running `chcp 65001` before calling pandoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the `chcp 65001` command before running the `pandoc` command solved the issue. Thanks [@tarleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2425163/tarleb) for providing  this suggestion.